# Creating XSD Schema from XML File

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd

I have a xml file.  I need to create xsd schema file. I tried to make code but resuts from my xsd schema  are Emptyfiles. I would be grateful for little help.
 I need XSD file to load in my sql server (SSIS).

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
    <ZoznamDanovychSubjektovRegistrovanychPreSpotrebneDane>
<CIS_SPDS>
      <DatumAktualizacieZoznamu>31052017</DatumAktualizacieZoznamu>
        <ITEM>
        <REGISTRACNECISLO>SK51000900001</REGISTRACNECISLO>
          <NAZOVSUBJEKTU>IMPREX, s.r.o.</NAZOVSUBJEKTU>
          <OBEC>Rimavská Sobota</OBEC>
          <PSC>979 01</PSC>
          <ULICA>Povstania 3/1677</ULICA>
          <DRUHDANENAZOV>Lieh</DRUHDANENAZOV>
          <DRUHDANESKRATKA>LH</DRUHDANESKRATKA>
          <DRUHDANSUBJ>Oprávnený príjemca - opakovaný</DRUHDANSUBJ>
          <DRUHDANSUBJSKRATKA>OPO</DRUHDANSUBJSKRATKA>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
          <REGISTRACNECISLO>SK51000900001</REGISTRACNECISLO>
          <NAZOVSUBJEKTU>IMPREX, s.r.o.</NAZOVSUBJEKTU>
          <OBEC>Rimavská Sobota</OBEC>
          <PSC>979 01</PSC>
          <ULICA>Povstania 3/1677</ULICA>
          <DRUHDANENAZOV>Víno</DRUHDANENAZOV>
          <DRUHDANESKRATKA>VN</DRUHDANESKRATKA>
          <DRUHDANSUBJ>Oprávnený príjemca - opakovaný</DRUHDANSUBJ>
          <DRUHDANSUBJSKRATKA>OPO</DRUHDANSUBJSKRATKA>
        </ITEM>
       </CIS_SPDS>
</ZoznamDanovychSubjektovRegistrovanychPreSpotrebneDane>
```

MY First XSD SCHEMA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element  name="ZoznamDanovychSubjektovRegistrovanychPreSpotrebneDane">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="DatumAktualizacieZoznamu" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
          <xs:element  name="CIS_SPDS">


          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ITEM">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="REGISTRACNECISLO" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="NAZOVSUBJEKTU" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="OBEC" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="PSC" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="ULICA" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="DRUHDANENAZOV" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="DRUHDANESKRATKA" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="DRUHDANSUBJ" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="DRUHDANSUBJSKRATKA" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>


</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Your DatumAktualizacieZoznamu tag is inside CIS_SPDS tag in your xml example but your xsd schema seems to validate it only when it is *outside* the CIS_SPDS tag.

Comment: Ok thanks. I' trying  corrected my mistake but XSD doesn't work properly. Even if I deleted "DatumAktualizacieZoznamu"  from xsd and xml.

Comment: My advice would be to look at practical and simple examples online.  Try to get them to work using those (providing stub xml examples).  Then adapt the fields little at a time until you have a working model and xsd.